# Why don't mongodb session MongoStore's go away after session ends?

Tags: node.js, session, mongodb, express

Even with

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    maxAge : new Date(Date.now() + 360000),
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 360000),//I've tried both separately
    store : new MongoStore(conf.db),


}));
```

The sessions in mongodb stay forever (as far as I have tested)

Are the session stores in MongoDB supposed to just stay there even after the session ends?
Because even with the maxAge or expires in the session declaration, in MongoDB, all the sessions look like this:

```
{ "_id" : "FU8k3kEzquG/hoSD308H5XHa", "session" : "{\"cookie
\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,
\"path\":\"/\"}}" }
```

Also, in most of my _id's there is some type of non-number/letter character, i.e. /, +, etc. Are they supposed to be like that?

Every time I re-open my browser, a new session is created, but the old one is still there in MongoDB. I just want to know if there is a fix to this, or if this is intentional.

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are the session stores in MongoDB supposed to just stay there even after the session ends?

This is the expected behaviour if your browser's cookie expires but the session information has been saved in a persistent backend data store like MongoDB.  The two data stores (backend versus browser-based cookie) can have different expiries.

Assuming you are using [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb) to persist the sessions, the default `reapInterval` should trigger removal of expired sessions every 60 seconds.

Since your session expiry is set to "null" these sessions would never expire.  The session expiry *should* be the same as the cookie `expires` value .. so if it's not being set you probably need to do a bit of debugging to track down the issue.

It's possible that these are old sessions saved before you tried setting the `maxAge`; I would check if new sessions are setting `expires` as you'd expect.  If so, you may need to manually delete some of the older non-expiring sessions.

> Also, in most of my _id's there is some type of non-number/letter
>   character, i.e. /, +, etc. Are they supposed to be like that?

Yes, Express sessionIDs are 24-character long alphanumeric strings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the explanation, Stennie!
I found out that I had to put

```
cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 360000)}
```

instead of

```
maxAge : new Date(Date.now() + 360000)
//or
expires: new Date(Date.now() + 360000)
```

I dropped my old session collection in my database (the data doesn't matter since I'm just testing stuff), so now I can see only the new sessions while testing. They now look as they should, and clear every clear_interval (equivalent to reapInterval in connect-mongo)